# go.Bar in python plotly (dash) - multiple stacked barplot from dataframe

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

that's probably a stupid question but I've been searching for hours pointlessly.

So, I have, let's say, the following dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

I want to make a stacked go.Bar plot where I see, for each day, the different 'totals' one over each other grouped by 'field'. I know that I could make several trace and stack them all into a dcc.Graph, but is there any way to do it straight away as in the third example from [this website](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/)? Or is it something only possible in plotly.express? In the website, it is done as follows:

```
import plotly.express as px
tips = px.data.tips()
fig = px.bar(tips, x="sex", y="total_bill", color='time')
fig.show()
```

Can I do in a quick&clean way like above? For example:

```
dcc.Graph(
    data = [go.Bar(
        x = df.data,
        y = df.total,
        color = df.field
        )],
    layout={})
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Plotly express uses plotly graph objects internally. The grouping with `color` seems to be a feature plotly express has built on top which plotly graph objects doesn't have. I would just go with the multiple trace route. You could take the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61746001/9098350).