# Plotly: How to define colors by variable/labels in plotly.graph_objects (Pie & Bar)

Tags: plotly, data-visualization, visualization, plotly-python, graph-visualization

I'm new to plotly, I have two different plots below (go.Pie & go.Bar) and I like to assign a color to each type (a: g) label as shown in the color_discrete_map. How do I include them in the codes for go.pie & go.bar? Thanks

Dataframe:
[image]

```
    color_discrete_map = {'a':'rgb(42,9,4)', 
                              'b':'rgb(111,203,209)',
                              'c':'rgb(55,165,172),',
                              'd':'rgb(29,127,136)',
                              'e':'rgb(2,84,92)',
                              'f':'rgb(4,37,42)'}
    
    unit_mix_pie.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=df.index, values=df['type']), row=1, col=1)


unit_mix_bar.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.index, y=round(df['type'],0), marker=dict(
        color=px.colors.qualitative.Pastel2, color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map,
        line=dict(color='#000000', width=2)
    )), row=1, col=1)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your case, we should at least be able to see what your DataFrame looks like so we can understand what your code does, but ideally we would be able to see more of your code as well including the `unit_mix_pie` object and so on

Comment: Hi @DerekO, thanks for your comment. Please see the edited post. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a little confused as to the point of `unit_mix_pie` and `unit_mix_bar` being subplots with only one row and one column - you could instead define each of these objects as a plotly graph_object or a plotly express figure.

If you define `unit_mix_pie` using plotly express, you can directly pass your `color_discrete_map` as a parameter:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'type':list('abcdefg'), 'no':[50,100,200,300,400,500,600]})

## added another color for the type 'g'
color_discrete_map = {'a':'rgb(42,9,4)', 
                          'b':'rgb(111,203,209)',
                          'c':'rgb(55,165,172)',
                          'd':'rgb(29,127,136)',
                          'e':'rgb(2,84,92)',
                          'f':'rgb(4,37,42)',
                          'g':'purple'}

unit_mix_pie = px.pie(df, values='no', names='type', color='type', color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map)
unit_mix_pie.show()
```

[image]

Then you can define `unit_mix_bar` as a plotly graph_object to add the bars individually uses traces, mapping their type to their color (I am borrowing from [vestland's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61746001/plotly-how-to-specify-colors-for-a-group-using-go-bar)):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

## add the bars one at a time
unit_mix_bar=go.Figure()
for t in df['type'].unique():
    dfp = df[df['type']==t]
    unit_mix_bar.add_traces(go.Bar(x=dfp['no'], y = dfp['type'], name=t,
                         marker_color=color_discrete_map[t]))
unit_mix_bar.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Derek O, Apologise for not making myself clear. You are right, there are 2 subplots, one with 2 go.pie and second with 2 go.bar. I'm able to tweak around to change from go.pie and go.bar to px.pie and px.bar.