# Pytho Plotly stockchart volume color change

Tags: python, plotly-python, plotly.js

I'm trying to change the color of the volume bar chart but I cant find the proper parameter.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['Date'], y=df['Volume'], showlegend=False), row=2, col=1)
```

This is the code of the bar chart which is added as a second plot in addition to OHLC plot. It is just a sample from the net. By default all of the bars are red for me so I wounder how can I change this color to black for ex. or base it on variable? Ive tryed to add something like color='black' but no luck

Comment: did you try `fillcolor="LightSkyBlue",` `line=dict(color="RoyalBlue",width=3)`

Comment: Just tried, not working, gives some errors regarding unknown parameters in both cases

Comment: you can use `marker_color=colors[t] `it has answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61746869/8208006