# What is the Plotly Graph_Objects equivalent of this Plotly_Express Code?

Tags: plotly

I've got a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date           Region         Rent

2014-10-01     Miami          1840

2014-10-01     Tampa          1340

...            ...            ...
```

when I use this Plotly_Express code it produces what I want

```
fig = px.line(Zori_filtered, x='Date', y='Rent', color='RegionName')

#fig.write_html("d:/downloads/zori.html")

fig.show()
```

[image: One line per region]

I want to produce the same graph with Graph_Objects so that I can attach another plot with similar data in another subplot.

I can't quite figure out how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: My example came out strange.  Here is what the dataframe looks like:
Date                    Region               Rent
2014-10-01         Miami                 1840
2014-10-01         Tampa                 1340
2015-11-01         Tampa                  1325

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: How to specify colors for a group using go.Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61746001/plotly-how-to-specify-colors-for-a-group-using-go-bar)

Comment: Linked question is about bar charts, but the same idea works here

Answer (score 0):

- you have not provided sample data so I have sourced from **kaggle** for demonstration purposes
- **Plotly Express** generates a trace for each *RegionName*, hence it's a simple case of using **pandas** `groupby()` in a list comprehension

```
go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(name=g[0], x=g[1]["Date"], y=g[1]["Rent"])
        for g in Zori_filtered.groupby("RegionName")
    ]
)
```

#### full code including data sourcing

```
import kaggle.cli
import sys, requests
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# fmt: off
# download data set
url = "https://www.kaggle.com/zillow/rent-index"
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + f"datasets download {urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path[1:]}".split(" ")
kaggle.cli.main()
zfile = ZipFile(f'{urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1]}.zip')
dfs = {f.filename: pd.read_csv(zfile.open(f)) for f in zfile.infolist()}
# fmt: on

Zori_filtered = dfs["price.csv"]

# structure data from kaggle in same way as dataframe in question is structured
Zori_filtered = Zori_filtered.loc[Zori_filtered["Population Rank"].lt(11)].set_index(
    Zori_filtered.columns[0:6].tolist()
).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={"level_6":"Date",0:"Rent"})
Zori_filtered["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(Zori_filtered["Date"])

Zori_filtered["RegionName"] = Zori_filtered["County"]+"-"+Zori_filtered["City"]+" - " + Zori_filtered["State"]

px.line(Zori_filtered, x='Date', y='Rent', color='RegionName').show()

# the answer...
go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(name=g[0], x=g[1]["Date"], y=g[1]["Rent"])
        for g in Zori_filtered.groupby("RegionName")
    ]
)
```

[image]